# Using Java 8 stream to calculate diference between two values and return the min

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a person class with name and age:

```
public class Person {
    private int age;
    private String name;
}
```

Having a list of persons and a specific person X, I want to know the person Y that is the nearest to X by age (i.e. X.age - Y.age is the min of comparing to all others):

```
public class Test {
    List<Pearson> persons // suppose this list contains elements

    public int calculate (Person p1, Person p2) {
        return  Math.abs(p1.getAge() - p2.getAge());
    }

    public Person process(Perosn X) {
        int nearest persons.stream()... // need help
    }
}
```

I want to use the Stream API but I don't know how, I tried the reduce but It doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the minimum difference between 2 numbers:

```
public Person process(Person px) {
    int age = px.getAge();
    return persons.stream()
                  .filter(p -> !p.equals(px))
                  .min(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> Math.abs(p.getAge() - age)))
                  .orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the [`min(Comparator<? super T> comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) method, e.g.

```
public Person process(Person pRef) {
    return persons.stream()
                  .filter(p -> ! p.equals(pRef)) // never find pRef itself
                  .min((p1, p2) -> Integer.compare(Math.abs(p1.getAge() - pRef.getAge()),
                                                   Math.abs(p2.getAge() - pRef.getAge())))
                  .orElse(null);
}
```

where `Math.abs(p1.getAge() - pRef.getAge())` is the *age difference* between `p1` and the reference person, i.e. always a positive number.

Comment: The "requirements" don't specifically state that you shouldn't match `pRef`.  You have made a reasonable assumption, but it isn't necessarily correct.

Comment: @Stephen Then it will always return the person x itself in the worst cases (if there won't be another person with the same age).

Comment: Well yea.   But that might be the CORRECT thing to do.  The point is that the OP does not specify whether or not that case needs to be handled differently.

Comment: This is one case where you _want_ to use `==` for object comparison in the filter.  You could theoretically have two _different_ people with the same name and same age and would not want to filter both out.

Comment: @StephenC If you don't exclude `pRef`, and it's in the list, you can only ever find one other arbitrary person of the *same* age. Since the objective is to find the person with the *nearest* age, the exclusion is implicit. Maybe it wasn't explicitly stated because `pRef` is guaranteed to not be in the list, in which case the filter is unnecessary, but harmless. However, I included it in the answer to point out a potential fallibility. It's up to OP whether to keep it.